# Can i control on my human model using blender

Tags: python, blender, 3dsmax, maxscript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i have the full control on my 3D human model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570727/how-can-i-have-the-full-control-on-my-3d-human-model)

I want to have full control on my 3D human model like scaling it,changing width and height etc. using blender scripts to integrate with it in my own project

If yes how to start
If no is there any other tool can do this ?

Comment: Update the original question with more information instead of asking the same question again.

Answer (score 1):

You start by learning blenders scripting language.
Yes it can also be done in 3dsmax, by either parameter wiring,
rigging, or by using maxscript.

You are very diffuse with your question.
what do you mean with "integrate it in my own project", what project?
animation project? blender project? realtime 3d project? etc

Good luck.